# How to hide tabLayout on scrolling when tablayout is at bottom

Tags: android

I have put my tab_layout at the bottom of my screen. I want it to hide when scrolling up and reappear when scrolling down.

I have tried collapsing toolbar layout, but it didn't work.
This is my code after using collapsing toolbar layout. Suggest me a new way, or point out the error. Or tell how to implement it programmatically in the java class.

**My code is here:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="org.kashiyatra.ky18.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@color/pink"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:tabContentStart="80dp"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/dark"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/dark"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/myTabText"
                tools:ignore="NotSibling" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

**You should use bottombar instead of tabbar**

Follow this:

https://android.jlelse.eu/scroll-your-bottom-navigation-view-away-with-10-lines-of-code-346f1ed40e9e

The blog can be sold your problem

Comment: recommend, use bottombar instead of tabbar

Answer (score 0):

You can control recyclerview with **addOnScrollListener** dy

```
 recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (dy > 0) {
                    tab_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else
                    tab_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: tab is in my main_activity and I can't access it from other activities

Comment: other activity or fragment ? if it is a fragment , so you can use supportActionBar 
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()  visibility bla bla ...